# add background image in laravel 5

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add a background image for my website in Laravel 5.

I've used this in my css file.

```
html {
        background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    }
```

the image is in the public folder of my Laravel project folder. I tried all the paths but it just doesn't load.

I keep getting this error:

```
http://Laravelproject.app:8000/background.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try adding / at the beginning and check the file permissions `background-image: url("/images/background.jpg");`

Comment: I tried that, i don't get any errors, but i still cant see the background image...

Comment: Run `http://Laravelproject.app:8000/images/background.jpg` in browser. Do you see the image?

Comment: i get notfoundHttpExtention error...

Comment: Is this image in `public/images` directory? If yes, it seems your web server is not configured correctly.

Comment: Please post the complete path of the file (so not the url).

Answer (score 20):

Might be answering a little late but do this and hope it helps someone out there:

```
background-image:url({{url('images/php_mysql.jpg')}})
```

Comment: It works on html: <a href="#" class="recent-work" style="background-image:url({{url('images/php_mysql.jpg')}})"> but if you add that -- background-image:url({{url('images/php_mysql.jpg')}}) -- to a example.css file  shows error, just giving you a heads up.

Answer (score 17):

Works just fine with slash:

```
html {
    background: url("/images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: then it must be insufficient file permission...and how do you mean normal css??

Comment: On Laravel 5.7 works file,  even though PHPStorm is complaining

Answer (score 6):

i am still unable to access image via css in Laravel 6

but

this code is work for me

(add image path in blade.php file)

```
<div id="loading" style="background-image: url('{{ asset('img/big-loader.gif')}}');">
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to get out of CSS first by adding two dots. Here I am going to show you an example, which I just tested and works fine in Laravel 5.7

1. Make new class in your CSS and name it login body.
2. Your css code should look like this.

   ```
   .loginbody 
   {
       background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
   }
   ```
3. Add this class to the body of the page where you want the image.
4. Save and run.

**Note:** be careful with your path, where the image exist. In my case the image is in "public/assets/images/bg.jpg"

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
   background-image: url({{asset('images/bg.jpg')}});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're in css, you need to get out of it first using the two dots.
url("../images/background.jpg");

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css of the specific class/id:

```
selector{
    background-image: url({{URL('/')}}/public/assets/landing/images/paper.jpg);
}
```

`{{URL('/')}}` means the base url of your project locations

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
background-image: {{asset("/images/background.jpg")}};
```

and my image is in `public/images`

Answer (score 0):

Please modify as following,

```
html{
 background-image: url('{{ asset('images/job.jpg') }}');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file, this is what worked for me:

```
background-image: url("../images/frontend_images/tempimages/hero.jpg");
```

Answer (score -1):

simple add above formate code :-

> url({{url('assets/images/slider/swiper/3.jpg')}})

Answer (score -2):

Try this code snippet, this one works on me :

```
url({{ URL::asset('images/SampleBackground.jpg')}})
```